# click button scroll to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that has a fixed menu and content box(div).
When click the menu,  content box scroll to specific div.

So far so good.

This is the sample here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ezrinn/8cdjsmb9/11/

The problem is when I wrap this whole div and, make them as show/hide toggle button, the scroll is not working.

This is the sample that not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/ezrinn/8cdjsmb9/10/

Also here is the snippet

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(".wrap").toggleClass('on');
});
 
var div_parent_class_name;
var divs_class;
var id_offset_map = {};
$(document).ready(function() { 
    div_parent_class_name = "wrap_scroll";
    divs_class = "page-section"; 

    var scroll_divs = $("." + div_parent_class_name).children();
    id_offset_map.first = 0;
    scroll_divs.each(function(index) {
        id_offset_map["#" + scroll_divs[index].id] = scroll_divs[index].offsetTop
    });

    $('a').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href")
        $('.wrap_scroll').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: id_offset_map[target]
        }, 600, function() {
            /* location.hash = target-20; */ //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });

        return false;
    });
});

$(".wrap_scroll").scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(".wrap_scroll").scrollTop();
    $("." + divs_class).each(function(i) {
        var divs = $("." + divs_class);

        divs.each(function(idx) {
            if (scrollPos >= id_offset_map["#" + this.id]) {
                $('.menu>ul>li a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.menu>ul>li a').eq(idx).addClass('active');
            }
            
        }); 
    });
}).scroll();
```

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 3000px;
}


.wrap { display:none;}
.wrap.on { display:block;}

.menu {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
}

.menu a.active {
    background: red
}

.wrap_scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll
}

#home {
    background-color: #286090;
    height: 200px;
}

#portfolio {
    background: gray;
    height: 600px;
}

#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 800px;
}

#contact {
    background: yellow;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">show/hide</button> 

<div class="wrap">  
  <div class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>a
  </div> 
  
  <div class="wrap_scroll">
      <div class="page-section" id="home">hh</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="portfolio">pp</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="about">aa</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="contact">cc</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What Do I need to fix the code? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate your `offset`, the `div` is `hidden` with `display: none`. This results in the offsets being set/calculated to zero.

Here's a quick fix I threw together: https://jsfiddle.net/hrb58zae/

Basically, moved the logic to determine offset after clicking show/hide.

```
var setOffset = null;

...

if (!setOffset) {
    var scroll_divs = $("." + div_parent_class_name).children();
    id_offset_map.first = 0;
    scroll_divs.each(function(index) {
        id_offset_map["#" + scroll_divs[index].id] = scroll_divs[index].offsetTop
    });
    setOffset = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, instead of using `display: none` and `display: block`, try using `visible` instead:

```
.wrap { visibility:hidden;}
.wrap.on { visibility:visible;}
```

This will hide the element without affecting the layout.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5u683es/

Comment: Thank you. simple to solve this problem with css :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you are trying to update id_offset_map when content was hidden. When you use 'display:none' prop you won't get dimensions for that element and so its not working.

I updated the logic please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qfrsmnh5/

```js
var id_offset_map = {};
var div_parent_class_name = "wrap_scroll";
var divs_class = "page-section"; 
var scroll_divs = $("." + div_parent_class_name).children();
   
function updateOffsets(){
    id_offset_map.first = 0;
    scroll_divs.each(function(index) {
        id_offset_map["#" + scroll_divs[index].id] = scroll_divs[index].offsetTop
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $(".wrap").toggleClass('on');
      if($(".wrap").hasClass("on")){
        updateOffsets();
      }
    });

    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href")
        $('.wrap_scroll').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: id_offset_map[target]
        }, 600, function() {
            /* location.hash = target-20; */ //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });

        return false;
    });
});

$(".wrap_scroll").on('scroll',function() {
    var scrollPos = $(".wrap_scroll").scrollTop();
    $("." + divs_class).each(function(i) {
        var divs = $("." + divs_class);

        divs.each(function(idx) {
            if (scrollPos >= id_offset_map["#" + this.id]) {
                $('.menu>ul>li a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.menu>ul>li a').eq(idx).addClass('active');
            }
            
        }); 
    });
}).scroll();
```

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 3000px;
}


.wrap { display:none;}
.wrap.on { display:block;}

.menu {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
}

.menu a.active {
    background: red;
}

.wrap_scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#home {
    background-color: #286090;
    height: 200px;
}

#portfolio {
    background: gray;
    height: 600px;
}

#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 800px;
}

#contact {
    background: yellow;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">show/hide</button> 

<div class="wrap">  
  <div class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="wrap_scroll">
      <div class="page-section" id="home">hh</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="portfolio">pp</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="about">aa</div>
      <div class="page-section" id="contact">cc</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

works perfectly, it's just that when you use display: none you can not do the offsetTop calculations because in fact the element is not rendered, I'm not sure if all the values ​​give 0 or undefined, I guess undefined, a solution is always calculate Positions using a function:

```
var div_parent_class_name;
var divs_class;
var id_offset_map = {};
function calcTops(){
    div_parent_class_name = "wrap_scroll";
    divs_class = "page-section"; 
    var scroll_divs = $("." + div_parent_class_name).children();
    id_offset_map.first = 0;
    scroll_divs.each(function(index) {
        id_offset_map["#" + scroll_divs[index].id] = scroll_divs[index].offsetTop
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/561oe7rb/1/

is not the optimal way, but it is to give you an idea. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Just Checkout This Working page I have designed

```js
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function(){
   onScroll();

  });
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   div_slider();
   showhide();
  });

  /*show hide content*/
  function showhide(){
   $('.toggle-wrapper button').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggle();
    // div_slider();
   })
  } 

  /*scrolling page on header elements click*/
  function div_slider(){
   $('ul li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var attrval = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: attrval.offset().top
    }, 1000)
   });
  }

  /*adding active class on header elements on page scroll*/
  function onScroll(event){
   var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
   $('ul li a').each(function () {
    var scroll_link = $(this);
    var ref_scroll_Link = $(scroll_link.attr("href"));
    if (ref_scroll_Link.position().top <= scrollPosition && ref_scroll_Link.position().top + ref_scroll_Link.height() > scrollPosition) {
     $('ul li a').removeClass("active");
     scroll_link.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
     scroll_link.removeClass("active");
    }
   });
  }
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
.toggle-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #ccd2cc;
 text-align: center;
}
.toggle-wrapper button {
 background-color: #ED4C67;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.toggle-wrapper button:active{
 background-color: #B53471;
}
header {
 background-color: #6C5CE7;
 position: fixed;
 top: 36px;
 z-index: 99;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
 header ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul li {
 flex: 1 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper {
 margin-top: 36px;
}
header a {
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: navajowhite;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
header a.active {
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
section {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
section.section1 {
 background-color: #FFEAA7;
}
section.section2{
 background-color:#FAB1A0;
}
section.section3{
 background-color:#7F8C8D;
}
section.section4{
 background-color:#4CD137;
}
section.section5{
 background-color:#A3CB38;
}
section.section6{
 background-color:#70A1FF;
}
section.section7{
 background-color:#079992;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-wrapper">
  <button>Toggle</button>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
  <header>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">six</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seven">seven</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  <section class="section1" id="one">SECTION ONE</section>
  <section class="section2" id="two">SECTION TWO</section>
  <section class="section3" id="three">SECTION THREE</section>
  <section class="section4" id="four">SECTION FOUR</section>
  <section class="section5" id="five">SECTION FIVE</section>
  <section class="section6" id="six">SECTION SIX</section>
  <section class="section7" id="seven">SECTION SEVEN</section>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```