# How do you toggle between two scroll positions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to toggle between two scroll positions (div elements) but I just can't figure it out. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm sorry if it's a simple thing.

Here's my scrollTo JS code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
   
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>




And the button:


<button class="material-icons floating-btn"><a href="#bookoffer" id="toggle-text">swap_vert</a></button> 


Thanks a lot. :)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: @DJHemath I want to have a toggle button that smoothly scrolls between two DIV elements. So when I click it the first time it scrolls to <div class="1">content</div> and when I click it for a second time, it scrolls to <div class="2">content</div>, and it repeats like that. Thanks for replying.

Comment: This should help a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155383/click-button-scroll-to-specific-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you an example of switching between two blocks using one button. The button works on the principle of a counter (0 and 1), and the selection is performed using the conditional `switch` operator.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var click_tag = 0;
  
  $('.button_location').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    
    switch (click_tag) {
    case 0:
      $('.button_location').attr('href', '#block2');
      click_tag = 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      $('.button_location').attr('href', '#block1');
      click_tag = 0;
      break;
     }
     
     var id = $(this).attr('href'),
     top = $(id).offset().top;
     $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 500);
  });   
  
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

.block:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}

.button_location {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block" id="block1"></div>
  <div class="block" id="block2"></div>
  <a href="#block2" class="button_location">button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Thank you! I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: glad to help ))